# Stuck after 'sxe ld' command

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I'm trying to setup break points on modules that are not loaded yet.

So I asked windbg to stop on module loading:

`sxe ld *xml*` (Just some random module for testing)

Then I saw this:

```
0:010> sxe ld *xml*
0:010> g
ModLoad: 70d10000 70e68000   C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll
eax=00000001 ebx=00000000 ecx=002a260c edx=0022017c esi=7ffd9000 edi=02259024
eip=775070b4 esp=02258f3c ebp=02258f90 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
775070b4 c3              ret
```

That output quickly showed, but windbg entered a 'BUSY' state. Why is that?

I have turned off address resolution with `.symopt+ 100`, I don't know why it stuck now, any way to find out?

(Running Windows 7 x86 in Virtrual Box)

Comment: How long does it stay in the busy state? What version of the debugger are you using? What does `bl` show prior to issuing `g`?

Comment: Do you run the debugger inside the VM or do you do remote debugging? Did you set symbols to be downloaded? Does the VM have Internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

load module exception is raised only once during the first load of module 
subsequent unloads and reloads of the same module in a session will not produce the LoadModule exception

unless you inadvertantly executed a go  sxe ld  should break the first time

```
:000> sxe -c ".echo lets break on any mod which contains u in its name;gc" ld *u*
0:000> .sxcmds
sxe ld:*u* ;
sx- -c ".echo lets break on any mod which contains u in its name;gc" ld ;
0:000> g
ModLoad: 77120000 771ab000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
lets break on any mod which contains u in its name
ModLoad: 769c0000 76a74000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
lets break on any mod which contains u in its name
ModLoad: 5ad70000 5ada8000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\UxTheme.dll
lets break on any mod which contains u in its name
ModLoad: 78130000 78263000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\urlmon.dll
lets break on any mod which contains u in its name
ModLoad: 3dfd0000 3e1b8000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\iertutil.dll
lets break on any mod which contains u in its name
ModLoad: 77920000 77a13000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
lets break on any mod which contains u in its name
```

Answer (score 1):

One potential reason could be that it is looking for symbols. 
What does your symbol path look like ?

Here is what you can try.

- Just for proof-of-concept. Set the symbols path to just some local folder on your machine.

If that indeed reduces the time Windbg is BUSY state.

- Run `!sym noisy` to observe what is taking so much time in looking for symbols.